# Appending Div Elements within a Cloned Object

Tags: javascript

I simply just want to add some data to the "employeeId" div element within a cloned object and can't figure out the proper syntax to do so.

Here is some of the layout of the original object:

```
<div id="container">
       <div id="reimbursement">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              Employee ID:
                <div id="employeeId">
                </div>
```

And here is the JavaScript that was used to create the clone:

```
        let reimbursement = document.getElementById("reimbursement");
        let reimbursementClone = reimbursement.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(reimbursementClone);
```

Comment: At this point I am just testing this process to see if I can get it to work (which I have thanks to DaCurse). Eventually I intend to pull data from an SQL database to fill out the various div elements (only "employeeId is shown) that are within the "reimbursement" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `querySelector` to get the element from the new clone and add the relevant data to it:

```js
let reimbursement = document.getElementById("reimbursement");
let reimbursementClone = reimbursement.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(reimbursementClone);
reimbursementClone.querySelector("#employeeId").innerText = "something";
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="reimbursement">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Employee ID:
        <div id="employeeId">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Although the above code would work, your cloning causes multiple instances of the same id which is invalid. You should change the `employeeId` to a class and pass a class selector to `reimbursementClone.querySelector`.

Comment: I don't see a big difference, just a different approach, anyways it would select the first element with that id, he is cloning an element that has an id and having multiple instances of and id is incorrect so in this case `querySelector` will get you the element you want.